# Equivalent of GetFeature POST request using GET? GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature

Right now I'm making `GetFeature` requests using WFS with http `POST` method. Due to project requirements I need to make these requests using `GET` method.

I'm facing serious issues traslating the POST body to a `GET` url query string.

This is the body:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetFeature xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" outputFormat="application/json" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
   <Query typeName="TRAC:v_expedientesmapa" srsName="EPSG:25830">
      <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
         <Contains>
            <PropertyName>geom</PropertyName>
            <Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:25830">
               <pos srsDimension="2">574026.178090231 4753824.833116741</pos>
            </Point>
         </Contains>
      </Filter>
   </Query>
</GetFeature>
```

And this is what I have achieved so far:

> http://foo.foo?service=wfs&version=1.3.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=TRAC:v_expedientesmapa

Don't know how to set the `contains` filter on the URL. I don't know how to add the `srs` either.

Comment: You have the wrong version for a WFS.  Version 1.3.0 is a WMS version, if you want `typenames` then you'll need version 2.0.0.  The service parameter must be `WFS`  not `wfs` to conform to the specification.

Comment: `http://foo.foo?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=TRAC:v_expedientesmapa&` will give you all the features in GML for features of type TRAC:v_expedientesmapa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will be

```
&filter=<Contains><PropertyName>geom</PropertyName><Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:25830"><pos srsDimension="2">574026.178090231 4753824.833116741</pos></Point></Contains>
```

suitably URL encoded